# "A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' " after buildint on a 64-bit computer

Tags: c#, .net, c, windows, visual-c++

My Visual Studio 2010 solution has C DLL and C# project, which calls C DLL.
Solution works ok when built on 32-bit Windows-7 Pro computer.
On 64-bit Windows-7 Pro, builds okay, but when ran, C# calls function in the DLL and gets error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException'
```

Solution Configuration Manager settings are:

```
<DLL project>   Platform = Win32       (<<< no option to change to "Any CPU")
<C# project>    Platform = "Any CPU"
```

The output below is:

1. C DLL BUILD OUTPUT
2. C# BUILD OUTPUT
3. RUN OUTPUT

C DLL BUILD OUTPUT:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Processing ..\..\..\include\USGFWSDK\include\Usgfw2.idl
1>  Usgfw2.idl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\oaidl.idl
1>  oaidl.idl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.idl
1>  objidl.idl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\unknwn.idl
1>  unknwn.idl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\wtypes.idl
1>  wtypes.idl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\basetsd.h
1>  basetsd.h
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\guiddef.h
1>  guiddef.h
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ocidl.idl
1>  ocidl.idl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\oleidl.idl
1>  oleidl.idl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\servprov.idl
1>  servprov.idl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\urlmon.idl
1>  urlmon.idl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\msxml.idl
1>  msxml.idl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\strmif.idl
1>  strmif.idl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\control.odl
1>  control.odl
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\oaidl.acf
1>  oaidl.acf
1>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ocidl.acf
1>  ocidl.acf
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>  DIBSectn.cpp
1>  sample.cpp
1>  sampleDlg.cpp
1>  Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Usgfw2_i.c
1>  .NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp
1>     Creating library C:\Primary\PROJECTS\VasoNova\WORK\Win7 VPS\Debug\Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber.lib and object C:\Primary\PROJECTS\VasoNova\WORK\Win7 VPS\Debug\Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber.exp
1>strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification
1>  sample.vcxproj -> C:\Primary\PROJECTS\VasoNova\WORK\Win7 VPS\Debug\Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber.dll
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

2) C# BUILD OUTPUT:

```
1>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: VNMath, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
2>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: GuiManager, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
4>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: VNCommon, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
4>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
5>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: AudioUtility, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
5>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
6>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: VNDevices, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
6>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
7>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: SimpleRPC, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
7>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
8>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: VNSockCommunication, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
8>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
9>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: PdfSharp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
9>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
10>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: VNUserControls, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
10>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
11>------ Skipped Rebuild All: Project: GuiServer, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
11>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
3>  Processing ..\..\..\include\USGFWSDK\include\Usgfw2.idl
3>  Usgfw2.idl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\oaidl.idl
3>  oaidl.idl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\objidl.idl
3>  objidl.idl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\unknwn.idl
3>  unknwn.idl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\wtypes.idl
3>  wtypes.idl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\basetsd.h
3>  basetsd.h
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\guiddef.h
3>  guiddef.h
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ocidl.idl
3>  ocidl.idl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\oleidl.idl
3>  oleidl.idl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\servprov.idl
3>  servprov.idl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\urlmon.idl
3>  urlmon.idl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\msxml.idl
3>  msxml.idl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\strmif.idl
3>  strmif.idl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\control.odl
3>  control.odl
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\oaidl.acf
3>  oaidl.acf
3>  Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\include\ocidl.acf
3>  ocidl.acf
3>  stdafx.cpp
3>  DIBSectn.cpp
3>  sample.cpp
3>  sampleDlg.cpp
3>  Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber.cpp
3>  Generating Code...
3>  Usgfw2_i.c
3>  .NETFramework,Version=v4.0.AssemblyAttributes.cpp
3>     Creating library C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\Debug\Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber.lib and object C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\Debug\Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber.exp
3>strmbasd.lib(mtype.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/INCREMENTAL:NO' specification
3>  sample.vcxproj -> C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\Debug\Ultrasound_Frame_Grabber.dll
12>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MY_APP, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APP\FrmMY_APP.cs(291,4): warning CS0162: Unreachable code detected
C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APP\FrmMY_APP.cs(441,4): warning CS0164: This label has not been referenced
C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APP\FrmMY_APP.cs(1276,13): warning CS0219: The variable 'exportFrmIsUp' is assigned but its value is never used
C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APP\FrmMY_APP.cs(91,66): warning CS0067: The event 'VN.Forms.MY_APPForm.m_eventTabletConnectionStatusChanged' is never used

Compile complete -- 0 errors, 4 warnings
12>  MY_APP -> C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APP\bin\Debug\MY_APP.exe
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\Common.Logging.dll
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\Common.Logging.Log4Net.dll
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\DistributedFileSystem.dll
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.dll
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\libMobiledevice.dll
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\log4net.config
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\log4net.dll
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\NetworkCommsDotNet.dll
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\protobuf-net.dll
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\QuickLZCompressor.dll
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\SerializerBase.dll
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\SevenZipLZMACompressor.dll
12>  C:\Primary\PROJECTS\my_project\WORK\Win7 VPS\\CommsLibrary\SharpZipLibCompressor.dll
12>         13 file(s) copied.
========== Rebuild All: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 10 skipped ==========
```

3) RUN OUTPUT:

```
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Primary\PROJECTS\VasoNova\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APPG4\bin\Debug\MY_APP.vshost.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Deployment\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Deployment.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceProcess\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.ServiceProcess.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 'vshost.NotifyLoad' (0x197c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x838) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'vshost.LoadReference' (0x1744) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Primary\PROJECTS\VasoNova\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APPG4\bin\Debug\MY_APP.exe', Symbols loaded.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Primary\PROJECTS\VasoNova\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APPG4\bin\Debug\VN.Common.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Primary\PROJECTS\VasoNova\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APPG4\bin\Debug\GuiServer.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Primary\PROJECTS\VasoNova\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APPG4\bin\Debug\GuiManager.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Primary\PROJECTS\VasoNova\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APPG4\bin\Debug\VNUserControls.dll', Symbols loaded.
'MY_APP.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Primary\PROJECTS\VasoNova\WORK\Win7 VPS\MY_APPG4\bin\Debug\VNSockCommunication.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

COMMS STEP 0: MY_APPForm_Load. MY APP NOW CALLS A C FUNCTION IN THE DLL, WHICH CAUSES THIS ERROR:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in MY_APP.exe
```

Comment: Try to restart your vs surprisingly, it worked with me!!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib...

Your program is running as a 64-bit process.  Your DLL contains 32-bit unmanaged code.  Kaboom.

You'll need to force your EXE to run as a 32-bit process so that DLL can be loaded.  Right-click your EXE project in the Solution Explorer window.  Properties, Build tab, change the Platform target setting from AnyCPU to x86.  On VS2012 and up tick the "Prefer 32-bit" option.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Comment: Thank you, Hans.  That solved it.  Note: I have VS2010 and could not find "Prefer 32-bit".  Hans, do you recommend upgrade to VS2012?  Is it worth it?

Comment: I had a similar problem, with the badimageformatexception, where I had added an external project that was building with platform target x86 (I'm working on a 64-bit machine). - I set the external project to build to 'any cpu', and all is good :)

Comment: Hans's answer is a clear bullseye. 

We go the exact error. But mine was not due to that though. We had number of machines running from Win Server 2008 R2, XP, Win 7 in 32/64 bit OS. As per these two questions, we needed to migrate old VB to .Net while using the interface .dll provided by the Finger Scanner machine. That third party .dll wasn't developed to accommodate the .Net framework assemblies.

Comment: As utterly trivial as it can be, our issue was that each time when we tried to connect to the finger scanner, it was disconnected by other means (port, itself, someone had unplugged). In the event if you happened to have this error, when everything else seems fine, it could be a silly action like a disconnected hardware.

Comment: If it's IIS 6.0/7.0 on an x64 machine you'll need to set `applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64` to true. [how-to](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7256924/1449056)

Comment: I just needed to change one of my dll's from x86 to Any CPU.